# Magento 2 script errors when running MAGE_MODE=production

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I've installed Magento 2 and set MAGE_MODE=production. However, I'm receiving a lot of JavaScript errors when visiting the home page (requireJS).

I tried flushing the cache and reploying static content files, to no avail.

[image]

I'm on the master branch of m2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generation of anything on the fly, including static content and classes, is prohibited in production mode. Once you enabled production mode and called `setup:static-content:deploy` it pre-generated everything needed to render the page. I would also recommend to run `setup:di:compile` and `dev:css:deploy`.

Alternatively you can run `deploy:mode:set`: it enables production mode, regenerates everything needed to be regenerated and changes the permissions on the filesystem. [Official documentation is here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton Eugene. This starts to make sense once you understand how everything works :) Nice suggestion on `deploy:mode:set` -- will definitely check that out. Sounds like that should be part of a pre-deployment build process when pushing code out to production.

Answer (score 4):

In MAGE_MODE=production static is not materialized at all. So you need run magento setup:static-content:deploy to materialized it. See more detail in [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html)

Answer (score 0):

So, I removed `/var/cache`, `/var/page_cache`, and `/var/view_preprocessed`, then ran `./bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. Now, everything is rendering correctly.

Does anyone know why this fixed it? The `setup:static-content:deploy` command also ran a lot faster after this was done.

Comment: setup:static-content:deploy generated missing files. Or is you question about why removing of var/cache, etc fixed it?